# dlopen errors with relative path

Tags: c++, macos, dlopen

I am trying to call a .dylib file from another .dylib file. They are in the same folder. I do this:

void* handle = dlopen("./other.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);

But handle winds up NULL and dlerror() says it can't find it. However, if I use a absolute path, it works. The docs say I can use a relative path. I am sure my spelling and case are correct.

Why does it error?

Answer (score 5):

A relative path is relative to your current working directory - not to the location of your first dylib